# Como copiar para área de transferência sem usar flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, área-de-transferência

o google Chrome esta exibindo uma mensagem de *"Esse site usa plug-in(Adobe Flash Player) que em breve não sera mais compatível"*.

Existe alguma forma de fazer sem Flash? Como?

E algo que de preferencia copie um atributo, por exemplo:

```
<a href="javascript:;" copy-to-clipboard="Isso aqui vai ser copiado">Copiar</a>
```

Copiar no caso apenas o valor que esta no atributo *copy-to-clipboard.*

Comment: Eu sei que tem como fazer isso no Google Chrome, no Firefox e Internet Explorer (acho) que só com flash.

Comment: Pois e, hoje tenho implementado com Flash.. so que esta aparecendo essa mensagem no Google Chrome e quero previnir.

Comment: Vê se isso ajuda https://www.npmjs.com/package/clipboard-js

Answer (score 4):

Este [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1698509) encontrado no stackoverflow internacional realiza a cópia para a área de transferência usando  `document.execCommand('copy')`  que atualmente é suportado pela versão mais recente dos principais navegadores.

### Exemplo

```js
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>
  <textarea class="js-copytextarea">Hello I'm some text</textarea>
</p>

<p>
  <button class="js-textareacopybtn">Copiar conteúdo</button>
</p>
```

Para informações adicionais e um exemplo mais complexo, acesse a [resposta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/1698509).

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma ainda melhor é trabalhar com a `api clipboard HTML 5` para fazer isso: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/working-with-clipboard-apis-in-html5-web-apps.html#fbid=eh9tM7GHJWF

Você pode consultar os browser suportados em: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Essa também foi uma resposta do `StackOverFlow` em inglês, em uma pergunta correspondente a sua. [How can I copy to clipboard in HTML5 without using flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336138/how-can-i-copy-to-clipboard-in-html5-without-using-flash)

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o [*clipboardJS*](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js#clipboardjs), este não possui dependências e não requer tecnologia Flash.

O único problema é o suporte, de acordo com o README são utilizadas as APIs [**`selection`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) e [**`document#execCommand`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) e os navegadores que suportam são:

- Firefox 41+
- Chrome 42+
- Internet Explorer 9+
- Opera 29+

---

#### básico:

Nesse exemplo é copiado o que estiver definido no atributo [*data-text*](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js#copy-text-from-attribute):

```js
new Clipboard('button');
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button data-text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'>
   copiar
</button>
```

#### copiando texto de outro elemento:

Nesse exemplo, será copiado o que estiver escrito no *input* de texto.

```js
new Clipboard('button');
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<input id='id-do-input' type='text' placeholder='Texto que será copiado...'/>
<button data-target='id-do-input'>copiar</button>
```

#### eventos:

Você pode obter as informações de sucesso ou falha ao tentar copiar algo para a área de transferência. Ative o console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>) para visualizar o *output* quando clicar no botão do *snippet* a seguir:

```js
var clip = new Clipboard('button');

clip.on('success', function(e) {
  console.info('Ação:', e.action);
  console.info('Conteúdo copiado:', e.text);
  console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger); // no caso de "copiar de outro elemento"

  e.clearSelection();
});

clip.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error('Ação:', e.action);
  console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button data-text='Testando eventos'>copiar</button>
```